# Splitting a Data Factor Pipeline based on the presence of a column

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm creating a pipeline to ingest a series of csvs into an Azure SQL Database

The CSVs come from a piece of medical software named **SystmOne**, the CSVs are either a *full* dataset or a *delta* dataset. The only difference in their schemas is the presence of an additional column: `RemovedData`.

The presence of this column will require an additional step in the pipeline (deleting any row from the database with `RemovedData == true`).

Is there a way in ADF or (ADF with Data Flow Preview) to query the file for the presence of a column and split the pipeline based on the result?

I have no control over the intial output of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the number of columns in your source dataset, with [getMetadataActivty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity#syntax) columnCount property, and then with If Activity do what you want.

[image: GetMetadataActivty]

Expression in IF activity: `@equals(activity('YourGet Metadata').output.columnCount,numberOfColumns)`

And then based on true or false you choose your dataset with propper schema.